# Jetpack Compose and ViewModel-Instantiation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What does the following line of code do?

```
fun NotesApp(noteViewModel: NoteViewModel = viewModel()) {
```

The default parameter confuses me. The class, which inherits from ViewModel, is called NoteViewModel.
Wouldn't the default parameter be: NoteViewModel()?

But it works nevertheless. How is that possible?

Comment: Is this a Composable?

Comment: @Richard Onslow Roper: Yep. It's within a Composable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the default initializer for view models inside a Composable. It takes in a type parameter, so I don't think what you've posted above would be enough.

For example, if you wanted to initialise a `MainViewModel`, it'll be something like

`val vm = viewModel<MainViewModel>()`

It is supposed to return the same instance of a viewmodel, if it had been created in the past.

Comment: Your answer with the default initializer makes sense to me. I guess in the case, I have shown, it takes the type-hint from "noteViewModel: NoteViewModel". Means: The "... : NoteViewModel ..." might be equivalent to <NoteViewModel>.

Answer (score 1):

It works because the function `viewModel()` provides that viewmodel. I assume it's from the `androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose` package.

> Returns an existing ViewModel or creates a new one in the given owner (usually, a fragment or an activity), defaulting to the owner provided by LocalViewModelStoreOwner.